# Debug/execução sem parar servidor

Tags: java, eclipse, debug

É possível parar uma execução que está em *debug* no momento do *breakpoint* sem parar o servidor?

Não quero que o *debug* continue porque sei que está errado, por exemplo quero que pare antes de dar um *insert* no banco, isso eu só consigo parando o servidor.

Answer (score 2):

Esta **não** é uma funcionalidade presente na IDE ou na JVM, porém há algumas técnicas que podem ser usadas na prática.

## Comente o código

Enquanto estiver no modo de depuração, parado no breakpoint, comente as linhas que não deseja executar e salve a classe.

Desde que não altere a declaração dos atributos da classe ou as assinaturas dos métodos, o Eclipse irá recompilar a classe e injetar a nova versão na JVM.

O breakpoint deve voltar para a primeira linha do método e você pode executá-lo sem afetar o banco de dados.

Nem sempre isso funciona tão diretamente. Ainda não descobri o motivo exato, mas alguns sistemas nos quais já trabalhei o plugin Servers do WTP simplesmente reinicia a aplicação sempre que uma classe é salva. Mas pelo menos o código não é executado.

## Altere o código

Ao depurar um código qualquer, você pode perceber algum "errinho". Ao invés de parar a execução, você pode simplesmente corrigir o erro e salvar a classe.

O resultado é equivalente ao que expliquei no tópico anterior.

## Modifique as variáveis

Para testar determinados cenários difíceis de reproduzir há uma técnica muito simples: modificar as variáveis na view *variables* do Eclipse.

Suponha que o resultado da expressão de um `if` retorna sempre verdadeiro para os cenários de testes implementados e seja grande o esforço para gerar um valor falso.

Nesse caso você pode colocar um breakpoint na linha `if` e alterar o valor das variáveis de forma a forçar a entrada no `else`.

O mesmo princípio pode ser aplicado para algum código com o qual você está tendo dificuldades em tester.

Por exemplo:

```
boolean entra = true;
if (entra) inserirRegistro();
```

No exemplo acima, basta modificar o valor da variável `entra` para `false` no Eclipse, enquanto mantém o *breakpoint* parado na linha do `if`, para então não ter o registro inserido.

Obviamente, só use isso para testes e remova o código desnecessário após corrigir o problema.